# Dummy operations handling of Intel processor

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, cpu-architecture, instruction-set

Admittedly, I have a bit silly question. Basically, I am wondering if
there are some special mechanisms provided by Intel processors to efficiently
execute a series of dummy, i.e., NOP instructions? For instance,I could imagine there
could be some kind of pre-fetch mechanism that identifies NOPS, discards them
and tries to fetch some useful instructions instead. Or are these NOPS dispatched
to the execution unit as normal instructions, meaning that i can roughly process
5 nops each cycle (under the assumption that there are 5 execution units)

Thanks,
Reinhard

Answer (score 2):

Discarding them would be pretty bad idea: they are often used for busy-waiting. If you discard `NOP`s, you make your wait-loop much tighter than it should be and potentially introduce considerable communications overhead.

If you feel that `NOP`s are inefficient, you could try `HLT` which saves some energy. Or you could even send the CPU into a sleep state. However, these only make sense if you want to "do nothing" for a considerable amount of time *and* they usually require suvervisor privileges.

Answer (score 1):

No.   They are decoded and executed as normal instructions; there is hardware support to remove the false dependency that would otherwise be introduced on the EAX register for the single byte NOP, 0x90 (which is really `xchg eax, eax`), but that's all.

Reference: [Intel(R) 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/248966.pdf) - section 3.5.1.8, "Using NOPs".

Answer (score 0):

There's very little need for optimizing sequences of no-ops on the x86 architecture because it has no-op encodings of varying lengths.  Instead of many one-byte no-ops, one can just use a single multi-byte no-op.  Somewhat more work for the decoder, but the actual execution units only see a single instruction to execute.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Does it make a difference from a performance point of view using a multiword versus a multi-single-NOP instruction? Or is this just interesting from a code size point of view?

Comment: It's hard to say exactly what the performance effects are for multi-byte NOPs.  I don't know if they can all go through the simple decoder path (you can probably look that up somewhere).  If they require the complex decoder path, and it's already saturated, it might be preferred to use two smaller NOPs.

Comment: Actually, with long NOP support you can make a single  NOP of any size from 1 to 15 bytes. If you need to skip a larger space, then JMP instead of NOP.