# Library for generating independent windows executable in Java or C++

Tags: java, c++, exe, executable-format, file-generation

I am **not** trying to compile my source code into an executable. Please read before marking as duplicate.

With that said, I apologize if this question has been asked before. The countless "how do I compile java | C++ to exe" questions filled up all my searches.

I am looking for a library that facilitates the creation of windows executable (.exe) files. To be specific, I want to be able to be able to generate a series of assembly instructions at runtime (these will be very simple) and create an executable that will execute them. I can generate the assembly myself; I would just like to have a library to help deal with all of the headers and other parts of the .exe file (I started looking into [Portable Executable File Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx) but it far too complicated for me to deal with. I'm not lazy but as a high-level programmer I feel that this stuff is way under my head). The specific mechanics of the library are not important as long as it works for either Java or C++. Java is highly preferred, however.

Any knowledge pertaining to any sort of framework that would be helpful in this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: Any number of free assemblers are floating around. Get one, have your Java program run it, use the resulting executable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compile code generated by a Java or C++ App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076075/how-to-compile-code-generated-by-a-java-or-c-app)

Comment: @n.m. I never though of that! Make that an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so what I ended up doing was searching around the `bin` folder of my MASM32 installation, where I found the assembler: `ml.exe`. I then write assembly to a text file and invoke the assembler on it using: `Runtime.exec()`:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
            "C:/masm32/bin/ml.exe "        //directory of assembler
            +"/coff "                      //create COFF header (needed for Win32)
            +"/Bl C:/masm32/bin/link.exe " //directory of linker 
            +"/Fe src/" + fileName + ".exe " //executable file
            +"/Fo src/" + fileName + ".obj " //object file
            + fileName + ".asm");            //assembly file (source)
```

[User n.m.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-m) gave me the idea, but as they didn't post it as answer after a month I decided to just answer it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Why not roll you own? Emit code for the lowest common denominator (CPU). By doing this you will probably add much to your skill set. I am currently writing a scripting engine and looking to introduce a JIT compiler to generate code for Windows platforms. To achieve this, I add code listings to projects to see assembly code generated by the compiler. Not perfect I know, but gives a solid starting direction.